# Using Multiple Containers and Replicas in Kubernetes Deployment for Efficient Scraping with Selenium

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a Kubernetes service that utilizes Selenium and a Python script for web scraping purposes. Given the high memory requirements of Selenium, I'm considering running multiple scripts simultaneously to improve efficiency.

Here's a simplified version of my YAML configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scraping-banner
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scrape-banner
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selenium-image
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:95.0.4638.69
      - name: function-image
        image: registry.gitlab.com/myrepo/scraping/functions:<VERSION>
      nodeSelector:
        type: scraping
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-registry
```

I know i could do something ugly like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scraping-banner
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scrape-banner
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selenium-image
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:95.0.4638.69
      - name: function-image-1
        image: registry.gitlab.com/myrepo/scraping/functions:<VERSION>
      - name: function-image-2
        image: registry.gitlab.com/myrepo/scraping/functions:<VERSION>
      - name: function-image-3
        image: registry.gitlab.com/myrepo/scraping/functions:<VERSION>
      nodeSelector:
        type: scraping
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-registry
```

But im looking something more "clean" like in docker-compose when you use:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: none
```

is that possible in kubernets yamls?

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

I chat a lot with openAI and searched in google for like 45 minutes and nothing appears to be what im looking for....

Comment: How is your application communicating with Selenium? Assuming it's over a network connection, the correct solution is to move selenium into a separate Deployment and then set `replicas` on your application Deployment to whatever number seems appropriate. Create a Service in front of Selenium and you should be all set.

Comment: We took this path because containers share some volumes with profiles and configs that are deployed when the function-image starts, but we could try to fix that and use your way